# How to make fluid with jQuery Isotope?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to make this demo fluid (change img size when window resize) with jQuery Isotope plugin, follow this [doc](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/fluid-responsive.html).
Did I do something wrong with my code?
Why is the window.resize seems not working? 
and use [doc](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/fluid-responsive.html) smartresize method neither.

Any suggestion will be appreciated, Thanks

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rBea8/1/)

HTML CSS

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/350" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/450" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/250" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/400" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/350" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/450" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/250" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/400" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" /></div>
</div>​

#container {
    background: black;
}
.item {
    width: 33px;
    float: left;
}
.item img {
    display: block;
    width: 33px;
}​
```

jQuery

```
$( function() {

    ww=$(window).width();
    $('#container').css({'width':ww});
    cw=$('#container').width();
    cw3=cw/3;
    $('.item').css({'width':cw3});
    $('.item img').css({'width':cw3});

    $('#container').imagesLoaded(function(){
        $('#container').isotope({
            masonry:{
            columnWidth: cw3
        }
    });
});

  // $(window).smartresize(function(){
  //     $('#container').isotope({
  //         masonry:{
  //             columnWidth: cw3
  //         }
  //     });
  // });
    $(window).bind("resize", function() {
        $('#container').isotope({
            masonry:{
                columnWidth: cw3
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

Make sure the code for calculating the `cw3` variable goes inside the `window.resize()` call.

```
$( function() {

    $(window).bind("resize", function() {

        ww=$(window).width();
        $('#container').css({'width':ww});
        cw=$('#container').width();
        cw3=parseInt(cw/3, 10);
        $('.item').css({'width':cw3});
        $('.item img').css({'width':cw3});

        $('#container').isotope({
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: cw3
            }
        });

    }).resize();

});​
```

*Fun fact: always include radix parameter in `parseInt()` call*

See http://jsfiddle.net/hongaar/9zJRh/3/

Comment: Is this also the solution to your problem or does it still persist?

Comment: Thanks for reply but my problem is I try to do like this demo http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/fluid-responsive.html or kind looks like this demo2 http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/myBxD  but demo2 is set with %, I want to figure how to use px

Comment: window.resize() or window.smartresize() it seems did't act anything in my code and I don't know why?

Comment: The variable `cw3` didn't get updated on window.resize, so resetting the isotope plugin there had no effect. I updated the jsfiddle