# Isotope configuration for masonry grid

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

​I'm trying to achieve the following layout using the masonry grid with Isotope.

[image: desired layout]

However, the code that is generated under my current setup has some 200px offsets that I can't seem to reconcile. This results in the following layout instead. The red arrows indicate how I need the pieces to move to look like the mockup above.

[image: current layout]

Below are two sets of code. The first set is the code that generates the faulty layout. The second set is the result of manipulating the style attributes' height, left, and top selectors in Chrome Inspector to set the correct top and left pixel values. This at least simulates what I want Isotope to do.

The pattern is clear that I seem to be off by 200px in some spots and more or less in others. But when I change the jQuery init code and/or CSS to that effect, in various combinations, I don't get the result I need. My brain apparently isn't big enough to figure out the right combo.

What values do I need to change and which parameters/attributes/selectors do I need to add or remove for Isotope to automatically generate the correct masonry layout?

**Incorrect Layout Code**

```
<div class="grid" style="position: relative; height: 600px;">
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2 wow zoomIn" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: visible;"><img src="img/placeholder400x400.png"></div>
    <div class="grid-item wow zoomIn" style="position: absolute; left: 600px; top: 0px; visibility: visible;"><img src="img/placeholder200x200.png"></div>
    <div class="grid-item wow zoomIn" style="position: absolute; left: 600px; top: 200px; visibility: visible;"><img src="img/placeholder800x200.png"></div>
    <div class="grid-item wow zoomIn" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 400px; visibility: visible;"><img src="img/placeholder800x200.png"></div>
    <div class="grid-item wow zoomIn" style="position: absolute; left: 600px; top: 400px; visibility: visible;"><img src="img/placeholder200x200.png"></div>
​</div>
```

**Correct Layout Code (after messing with it in Inspector)**

```
<div class="grid" style="position: relative;height: 400px;">
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2 wow zoomIn" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: visible;"><img src="img/placeholder400x400.png"></div>
    <div class="grid-item wow zoomIn" style="position: absolute;left: 400px; top: 0px; visibility: visible;"><img src="img/placeholder200x200.png"></div>
    <div class="grid-item wow zoomIn" style="position: absolute;left: 600px; t;top: 0;visibility: visible;"><img src="img/placeholder800x200.png"></div>
    <div class="grid-item wow zoomIn" style="position: absolute;left: 400px;top: 200px; visibility: visible;"><img src="img/placeholder800x200.png"></div>
    <div class="grid-item wow zoomIn" style="position: absolute;left: 1200px;top: 200px; visibility: visible;"><img src="img/placeholder200x200.png"></div>             
​</div>
```

And here are the CSS and jQuery.

**CSS**

```
/* ---- grid ---- */
.grid {
  max-width: 1400px;
  position: relative;
}
/* clear fix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
/* ---- .grid-item ---- */
.grid-item {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.grid-item--width2 { width: 400px; }
.grid-item--height2 { height: 400px; }
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  masonry: {
    columnWidth: 600
  }
});
```

I did try the obvious thing of setting `columnWidth: 400`​, but that only got me the following layout.

[image: almost, but not quite]

Close, but still off by 200 for the top placeholder and off by 400 for the bottom placeholder.

Can this specificity of layout even be achieved using Isotope?

Comment: Thanks. What I failed to make clear is that the style="" attributes are generated dynamically at page load by the Isotope component. It takes its values from the jQuery init code and from what's in the CSS. Adding one's own style attributes gets overwritten by the jQuery in Isotope. What I need is the correct setup values in Isotope to ensure that this layout occurs. Unless I'm misunderstanding what was in your fiddle of my code?

Comment: Here is a fiddle with isotope included: https://jsfiddle.net/Hunter377/9g0cgwp3/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `masonry: { columnWidth: 600 }` and use `layoutMode: 'packery'` instead. Set your `.grid-item` width to auto, and it should work as desired.

**JavaScript**

```
$('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  layoutMode: 'packery'
});
```

**CSS**

```
.grid-item {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
```

[**Working Codepen**](http://codepen.io/Hunter377/pen/qbwoZq)

(or if you prefer)

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9g0cgwp3/7/)

***Note** To use packery, you must include the packery JavaScript. I included it in the JavaScript of the pen itself because the external link wasn't working.

Comment: Thank you! This works great! Now I'm trying to figure out how to make the images shrink dynamically as well as the viewport resizes. In case anyone's interested, this is the SO thread about that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379968/how-to-make-fluid-with-jquery-isotope?rq=1

Comment: No problem buddy :) This was a fun one to work on, haha. Thanks for the link! I'll have to take a look.

Comment: I was taking an online course on Bootstrap last night and discovered the `img-responsive` class which takes care of the image scaling problem without the complexity of the code at that link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `columnWidth` to be equal with smallest `.grid-item`. In your case, from images with placeholders, your smallest is 200px width. http://jsfiddle.net/QsCZx/452/

```js
$('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  masonry: {
    columnWidth: 200 //smallest .grid-item
  }
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle does not reflect the desired result shown above.